# Как правильно передать данные из COM порта

Tags: c++, qt, qml, com-port

В COM порт поступают данные вида 0,0,999,000000110: , получив строку ее надо привести к виду 0,0,999,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0... чтоб в последующем я смог в QML файле обратиться к любому из них, что я собственно и реализовал:

```
void SerialPort::onReadData()
{
    if(arduino->bytesAvailable()>0){

      QByteArray data = arduino->readAll();
      QString value = QString(data).trimmed(); 
      QStringList sl = value.split(",");
      QString qqq;
      std::vector<QString> fullData;
      fullData.reserve(sl.size() + 12);
      for(int i = 0; i < sl.size()-1; i++)
          fullData.push_back(sl[i]);
      QString lastItem = sl[sl.size()-1];
      lastItem.chop(2);
      for(int i = 0; i < lastItem.size(); i++)
         fullData.push_back(QString(lastItem[i])); 
      for(int i = 0; i <fullData.size(); i++)
         qqq+= fullData[i]+',';
      set_serial_data(qqq);
      //qDebug()<< qqq ;
    }
}
```

и сам вывод

```
 SerialPort
    {
        id: cppClass
    }

    Text
    { 
        text: cppClass.serial_data[5] 
    }

    Text
    { 
        text: cppClass.serial_data[2] 
    }
```

Проблема в том, что данные в этой ячейке к которой я обращаюсь скачет(меняется). Посмотрев Debug , увидел что есть моменты где считает до 4 числа и начинает счет заново с 0. Получается, что данные не успевают отобразиться как уже переписываются. Еще постоянно выскакивает ошибка **unable to assign [undefined] to QString**
Как сделать так, чтоб я получил массив своих чисел 0,0,999,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0 - потом считал их, через определенный промежуток времени опять, получил - считал... ?

Comment: как минимум, не правильно работаешь с портом... `readAll()` может вернуть и 1 байт и двадцать строк данных...

Comment: Подскажи тогда пожалуйста, как правильно....

Comment: какой в точности форма данных ожидается? чем отделяются друг от друга записи?

Comment: запись идет одна статического размера 12 значений такого вида, 0,0,999,000000110:  , первые 4 значения идут аналоговые сигналы разделенные запятой, далее все остальные цифровые 0 или 1...   Мне надо их занести в массив , чтоб я мог к каждому из них обратиться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> запись идет одна статического размера 12 значений такого вида, `0,0,999,000000110:`

Ожидать, что `readAll()`  будет возвращать одну целую запись не следует, для такого медленного интерфейса как последовательный порт сигнал `readyRead()`, вероятней всего будет прилетать на каждый байт. Так что данные необходимо накапливать по мере получения, после получения целой записи просматривать полностью. Типовое чтение будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом (не отлажено):

```
class SerialPort {
//...
private:
  QByteArray dataBuffer;
}

//...

void SerialPort::onReadData () {
  QByteArray dataRecv = arduino->readAll ();
  int sepPos = dataRecv.indexOf (':');
  int dataBufSz = dataBuffer.size ();

  dataBuffer.append (dataRecv);

  if (sepPos!=-1) {
    int recStart = 0;
    sepPos += dataBufSz;
    do {
      processSingleRecord (dataBuffer.mid (recStart, sepPos - recStart));
      recStart = sepPos + 1;
      sepPos = dataBuffer.indexOf (':', recStart);
    } while (sepPos!=-1);

    dataBuffer = dataBuffer.mid (recStart);
  }
}

void SerialPort::processSingleRecord (QByteArray data) {
  // ... разбор полученной записи и связанные действия
}
```

По поводу вопроса: возможны и другие ошибки.

Comment: я получил массив в виде строки \n0,0,999,0,0,00001100....  Правильно я понимаю, теперь строка вначале читается полностью, и только потом просматривается ?
как бы мне теперь их разбить по символьно , а то мой вариант теперь не работает.... (чтоб получилось 0,0,999,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0)
И вывод в qml у меня теперь только целой строкой получается 
text: cppClass.serial_data  , а надо бы text: cppClass.serial_data[1] и т.д.

Comment: >`...и только потом просматривается ?`< — да... как разбить — думаю сам справишься; это уже типовая задача, так что думай, отлаживай и успехов.... в код выше, честно сказать не вникал... как работать с qml я понятия не имею, так что эту часть даже не понял....